# Do scriptures say to take sannyas only after permission from wife or mother?

Tags: scripture, sannyasa

Can sannyas be only taken after prior permission from family?
Were there any instances of sages who took sannyas without permission from their spouse or mother?

Comment: Somebody I heard of went to Swami Sivananda and wanted to be a Sannyasi.  Sivananda discovered he was just trying to escape from life's problems and told him to go back to his family.

Comment: If one feels urge and renounces there is no mother, no relative etc. One saint upon meeting his parents only wished that they both forget each other

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there are some scriptures which state that before renouncing one must first take approval of the family.

> [31] "He who renounces in the proper order1 becomes a renunciant."
> "What is it that people call renunciation? And how does one become a
> renunciant?" 2 "A man who has protected himself well by rites3
> **should obtain the cheerful approval of his mother, father, wife, sons, friends, and relatives**. Having invited as before all the
> priests who usually officiate for him, he should offer a sacrifice to
> Agni Vaisvanara and give all his possessions.
>
> *Katha Sruti Upanishad, Chapter 1*

Similar instruction is found in another Sannyasa Upanishad too:

> From home he should first become a forest hermit and then renounce. Or
> rather, he may renounce directly from Vedic studentship, or from home,
> or from the forest. Let him even renounce on the very day that he
> becomes detached, regardless of whether he has taken the vow or not,
> whether he has graduated or not, and whether he has kindled the sacred
> fire or is without a fire. Realizing this, a Vedic student, a
> householder, or a forest hermit, who is detached from everything
> relating to samsara, [should renounce] 2 **after he has obtained the
> cheerful approval of his father, mother, wife, son, and the circle of
> close relatives, or, in their absence, the consent of his pupil or a
> fellow resident**
>
> *Paramhamsa Parivrajaka Upanishad, Chapter 2*

Both these Upanishads are minor ones and they deal extensively with Sannyasa.

Comment: from common sense one can say that such things should not be neccesary,

Comment: Which things should not be necessary? @Youwillnotknowme

Comment: permission from the said persons

Comment: In Hinduism before starting any tasks scriptures recommend to first take permission from one's Guru and elders ... So how could this instruction be against "common sense" is beyond me .. Anyway it's a scriptural requirement and even Adi Shankara took his mother's permission before taking Sannyas completely abandoned by his "common sense" @Youwillnotknowme

Comment: Manu says -- 2.229. Obedience towards those three is declared to be the best (form of) austerity; **let him not perform other
meritorious acts without their permission.**  .. here "three" refers to one's Guru and parents. So it's actually quite a common thing in Hinduism to take permission from elders before starting anything significant as opposed to something against "common sense"

Comment: I do agree with you on this, but do you think will every parent allow to take sanyas(no) so for that thing such rules should not be there, and there is example of bharat who did not agree with kaikeyi

Comment: Rule is there , if parents don't approve they should not disobey them @Youwillnotknowme